# How to write multiple matrices to a file in Matlab without being over written

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to write three different matrices to a file by using the following code.

```
REF=[0 6;
     1 6;
     2 6;
     5 6;
    10 6;
    50 6;
   100 6;
  1000 6];
dlmwrite('exp.txt',REF,'delimiter','\t','precision',4)

A1=[0 6;
     1 3;
     2 4;
     5 4;
    10 4;
    50 4;
   100 4;
  1000 4];
dlmwrite('exp.txt',A1,'delimiter','\t','precision',4)

A2=[0 8;
     1 8;
     2 8;
     5 8;
    10 8;
    50 8;
   100 8;
  1000 8];
dlmwrite('exp.txt',A2,'delimiter','\t','precision',4)


fclose(fileID);
```

But when I run my program, only the last matrix exists in the file, all previous data has been over written. How can I write multiple matrices to a single file without being over written?

Comment: From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html), use `'-append'` to append the data to the end of the file.

Comment: It's also pointless to use `fopen` with `dlmwrite`. `dlmwrite` opens the file internally.

Comment: "append" adds data at the end of single matrix. But I want all three matrices to be available in the file as separate entities. So that when I load the file to another program, I should get three matrices.

Comment: append adds to the "existing file". So when you write A, you have A in exp. Then you "append" B to the file so you have A and B . Then you add C so you'll  have A , B and C in exp.txt

Comment: So write a blank line after each `dlmwrite` call or add a `'rowoffset'` like the existing answer already does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-append` :

```
REF=[0 6;
     1 6;
     2 6;
     5 6;
    10 6;
    50 6;
   100 6;
  1000 6];
dlmwrite('exp.txt',REF,'delimiter','\t','precision',4)

A1=[0 6;
     1 3;
     2 4;
     5 4;
    10 4;
    50 4;
   100 4;
  1000 4];
dlmwrite('exp.txt',A1,'delimiter','\t','precision',4, '-append','roffset',1)

A2=[0 8;
     1 8;
     2 8;
     5 8;
    10 8;
    50 8;
   100 8;
  1000 8];
dlmwrite('exp.txt',A2,'delimiter','\t','precision',4, '-append','roffset',1)
```

Result:

```
0   6
1   6
2   6
5   6
10  6
50  6
100 6
1000    6

0   6
1   3
2   4
5   4
10  4
50  4
100 4
1000    4

0   8
1   8
2   8
5   8
10  8
50  8
100 8
1000    8
```

**P.S.** 
You can also use fprintf to have the names of your matrices:
Code:

```
fileID = fopen('exp.txt','w');
REF=[0 6;
    1 6;
    2 6;
    5 6;
    10 6;
    50 6;
    100 6;
    1000 6];
A1=[0 6;
    1 3;
    2 4;
    5 4;
    10 4;
    50 4;
    100 4;
    1000 4];
A2=[0 8;
    1 8;
    2 8;
    5 8;
    10 8;
    50 8;
    100 8;
    1000 8];
fprintf(fileID,'%s\n','REF = ');
fprintf(fileID,'%d %d\n', REF);
fprintf(fileID,'\n%s\n','A1 = ');
fprintf(fileID,'%d %d\n', A1);
fprintf(fileID,'\n%s\n','A2 = ');
fprintf(fileID,'%d %d\n', A2);
fclose(fileID);
```

Result:

```
REF = 
0 1
2 5
10 50
100 1000
6 6
6 6
6 6
6 6

A1 = 
0 1
2 5
10 50
100 1000
6 3
4 4
4 4
4 4

A2 = 
0 1
2 5
10 50
100 1000
8 8
8 8
8 8
8 8
```

P.S.2

```
save('mydata.mat','REF', 'A1', 'A2');
```

then

```
load('mydata.mat');
```

Comment: "append" adds data at the end of single matrix. But I want all three matrices to be available in the file as separate entities. So that when I load the file to another program, I should get three matrices.

Comment: @Habib.Khan I don't understand your meaning. Doesn't the my result have all A B and C ?

Comment: @Habib.Khan The above output does exactly what you want.  Write a program to detect line breaks so you can delineate between the separate matrices.  If you don't want to do this, then don't use a text file.  Use an actual MATLAB MAT file to save the three matrices.  That's what MATLAB MAT files are for.  Why are you reinventing the wheel?  Stick with accepted MATLAB practices.

Comment: OK. I can use MAT files. How can I save the data as three different matrices available in one MAT file. Can you suggest a way?

Comment: @Habib.Khan I've updated my answer using fprintf in case you wanted to parse the text file under a different programming language. Please accept the answer if it is what you wanted

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator. Thank you for the reply. Your answer does what i explained in the problem. I thought to use the exp.txt file as input to another Matlab program which uses these three matrices as input and perform some computation. When I used the exp.txt, Matlab fails to separate the three matrices. Can you suggest some other way so that I have three separate Matrices available for computation.

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator.Thank you very much for the new solution. It solves my purpose.